# Deleting duplicate values from a sorted singly linked list

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to delete duplicate values from a sorted singly linked list.

this is my code

SinglyLinkedListNode* removeDuplicates(SinglyLinkedListNode* head)
{

```
if(head==NULL)
     return head;

  int flag=0;
  SinglyLinkedListNode* p,*q,*temp;

  for(p=head;p->next!=NULL;p=p->next)
      {
          if(flag==1)
             {
                 p=temp;
                 flag=0;
             }

          q=p->next;

          if(q->data==p->data)
             {
                 temp=p;
                 p->next=q->next;
                 free(q);
                 flag=1;
             }
      }

      return head;
```

}

However the code fails when Singly linked list is 3->3->3->4->5->5->NULL

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code-

```
void removeDuplicates(SinglyLinkedListNode* head)  
{  
    SinglyLinkedListNode* current = head;  
  
    SinglyLinkedListNode* nextNode;  
      
    if (current == NULL)
    return;  
  
    while (current->next != NULL)  
    {  
    if (current->data == current->next->data)  
    {       
        nextNode = current->next->next;  
        free(current->next);  
        current->next = nextNode;
    }  
    else
    {  
        current = current->next;  
    }  
    }  
}
```